# Pyqtgraph horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, pyqt5, bar-chart, pyqtgraph

I am able to create a vertical bar chart using following code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

window = pg.plot()

y1 = [5, 5, 7, 10, 3, 8, 9, 1, 6, 2]
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
bargraph = pg.BarGraphItem(x=x, height=y1, width=0.6)
window.addItem(bargraph)
```

**Result:**

[image]

But now i need to plot a horizontal bar chart:

[image]

How can i do this using `pyqtgraph`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just spin your brain 90 degrees...

Parameters:

- `x0` is the left side of the bars (zero in most cases).
- `y` becomes the domain (linear series) instead of x.
- `height` becomes the bar "thickness", for aesthetics.
- `width` becomes the bar "length", or output values.

[BarGraphItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/bargraphitem.html)

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

window = pg.plot()

x1 = [5, 5, 7, 10, 3, 8, 9, 1, 6, 2]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
bargraph = pg.BarGraphItem(x0=0, y=y, height=0.6, width=x1)
window.addItem(bargraph)
QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

example horizontal bar graph

[image: example horizontal bar graph]